# Wired CSS rendered in chrome (but not in Safari)

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I've seen such issue in lots of sites.. and [Google Big Query Docs Page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/) is just one of them.

In safari, it renders perfectly fine:

[image: what I get in Safari]

However, in Chrome, it renders like this:[image]

It happens with the latest build of Chrome, and it happens on lots of sites, for example, [Left sidebar of CircleCI Admin Pannel](https://circleci.com/dashboard)

I've tried reset Chrome, and it doesn't solves the issue.

Any idea what has been wrong?

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in? Ctrl + 0 to reset it to 100%.

Comment: No problems this end. What is the version of Chrome? Is it on Mac?

Comment: SO is here to help with code and markup that you wrote and want help solving, not what others wrote. Nor is it here to debug general purpose user software issues. Your question is off-topic.

Comment: @Morpheus Yes it's on Mac. It's both on Chrome: `Version 54.0.2840.71` and `Version 56.0.2897.0 canary (64-bit)`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly The zoom has been reset already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the icon font not rendering, or being blocked. What you are seeing is fallback textual content.

I get the same result if I disable `font-family: 'Material Icons';`

Comment: Thx for your reply. Following ur inspiration, I fount this page: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/348. It turns out that I have `MaterialIcon-Regular` installed locally somehow, and it clashed.